# How to display the content of asp.net cache?

Tags: c#, caching, reflection, dynamic, casting

We have an asp.net MVC web application which uses the HttpRuntime.Cache
object to keep some static lookup values. We want to be able to monitor what's
being cached in real time to allow us to pinpoint some possible caching issues.

Since this object isn't strongly typed when reading from it, we need to dynamically
cast each entries to it's concrete type.

Most of the cached items are of IEnumerable where T can be any classes we use in our
project or new ones that could eventually be added as the project goes further.
Can someone give me a pointer on how to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you think the fault may be? It could help with suggestions on how to monitor it rather than this potential sledgehammer approach.

Comment: It's for detecting issues that "might" occur so we don't know in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ASP.NET MVC itself.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(HttpRuntime.Cache)
}
```

and for the view

```
Html.DisplayForModel()
```

You will want to use a custom object template (basically take the MVC template and turn off the depth restriction).

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

On the object template you will want to alter

```
else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) { %>
    <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText %>
```

And change the > 1  to either be a higher number like 5-10 or just completely remove this depth check (I'd probably start with a 5 and go from there).

Comment: That seems the very best way to do it but, can you elaborate a little bit more on how you suggests me to do it? I mean, about the template, what do I need to do to get this going?

Comment: You need to create the template under Views < Shared < DisplayTemplates (or EditorTemplates), note if you make it directly Object.ascx / Object.cshtml this will be used for ALL usages of DisplayFor or DisplayForModel that reaches an object type. You could name it whatever you want and then in the DisplayForModel("templateName"), the file does need to be in the Shared folder (possibly in the Templates folder but calling it by name I'm not sure off hand)

Comment: But how this template will figure out how to display the informations store in the cache? I mean, since it's an object type, in the template, I cannot access any properties and beside, since it can be anything, how could I be able to do such thing without having to code specific type casting per type code?

Comment: That's what I'm saying if you use that object template directly with the depth increased or turned off you don't need to do any work PERIOD. You will leverage MVC model binding to decompose the Cache bag into 100s or 1000s of properties in a tree structure, every property will eventually boil down to a string, int etc primitive type which it has no problems displaying. MVC model binding will traverse the object graph for you.

Comment: I understand now! Pretty straightforward actually, I just had some misconception about the custom templating. Now, it works like a charm and does exactly what we needed!   Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to Json serialize it using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class. This way you don't need to cast to the original type as the `Serialize` method can take any object and output it in a humanly readable JSON format. It might choke on some complex types and if this happens you may also try the [Newtonsoft Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

Comment: Interesting! But I'm having problems figuring out on how to use this to achieve what we need.   Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Stéphan, like this: `string result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(someObjectInstance)`; where `someObjectInstance` can be just about anything. So you could loop through the values in the cache and serialize them like this.

Comment: As I suspected, my objet graphs in the cache are rather large and I get a message: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.   I tried to set my serializer's MaxJsonLength property.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to highlight that the cache exists in the App Domain for the MVC web app so wouldn't be accessible externally, you'd need to either implement some in-app monitoring or inter-App Domain comms to enable an external app to request the cache data from your MVC App Domain.

Comment: True, and for the record, our cache manager would be in the very same web app so, it's not a concern but, thanks for clarifying it for others that might know this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I *think* what you are asking for is a way of determining what the type parameters of a generic type is at runtime - in your example the situation is complicated because you are after an interface not an object instance.

Nethertheless this is still pretty straightforward, the following example should at least point you in the right direction on how to do this:

```
object obj= new List<string>();
Type type = obj.GetType();

Type enumerable = type.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
if (enumerable != null)
{
    Type listType = enumerable.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    if (listType == typeof(string))
    {
        IEnumerable<string> e = obj as IEnumerable<string>;
    }
}
```

But I can't really see how this helps you solve your underlying problem of monitoring your cache?

In the past when attempting to monitor the performance of caches I've found creating my own simple Perfmon counters very helpful for monitor purposes - as a basic example start with a "# Entries" counter (which you increment whenever an item is added to the cache and decrement whenever an item is removed from the cache), and add counters as that you think would be useful as you go - a cache hit counter and a cache miss counter are normally pretty useful too.

You can also have your Perfmon counter break down caching information by having many instances of your counters, one for each type being cached (or in your case more likely the generic `IEnumerable` type being cached) - just as the "Process" perfmon counter group has an instance for each process on your system, you would have an instance for each type in the cache (plus you should also add a "_Total" instance or similar).

Using Perfmon counters by recording operations on the cache allows you to monitor your cache performance in a fair amount of detail with very little runtime performance overhead.