# View cached data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

Is there any third party tool or something in visual studio that lets you see the cached objects?

For example, an action is caching data (varied by parameters) and I want to see the cached objects and the attributes (like which parameter values were sent to the action when this data was cached).

Comment: Are you looking to iterate the cached objects in your Application Domain? If so [system.web.httpcontext.cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) is a good place to start. You can reference it in code and set a break and then inspect it's contents with a watch in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more answers to what you might desire on the Stackoverflow question:
[How to display the content of asp.net cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884470/how-to-display-the-content-of-asp-net-cache)

Basically you can create a page to view all cached items from your application. After that, it can customize and UI pump it to your needs and objectives.

If you just need to debug, then you can use Ringer's solution displayed on your comments.