# How can I diagnose caching issues?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, appharbor

I am using Asp.net-MVC and hosting on AppHarbour.

I have noticed two very strange behaviours that are indicating to me that I have some caching issues, and as much as I have tried to resolve them they are sticking around.

In the first case, when I hit certain pages, they are bringing back old content.

No big mystery, the problem is since I found this, I cleared my browser cache, even switched browsers to one I don't use, and added in a global filter to disable all caching.

It's still caching it!? What else can I try? How can I better diagnose the issue?

The second problem, is similar but it is a new controller that has been added, sometimes hitting it creates a 404 othertimes it works just fine?

There are no errors occuring in the logs aside from these symptoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a page that displays a list of all cache entries. This way you can check if the global cache filter is realy working.

This link shows how:
[How to display the content of asp.net cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884470/how-to-display-the-content-of-asp-net-cache)

Comment: awesome, I will give it a go tonight.